# Iron:router landing page AFTER login

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Folks, I am making progress, but I am certain that there is a better, more elegant way to accomplish this functionality. As before, I want users to "always" be directed to a welcome page once they log into the application, even if they were previously signed-out at a different page. What trips me up is the "this.next()" requirement for iron Router's onBeforeAction.

Briefly a scenario:

1) User navigates to the application and is prompted with a "Welcome but please sign-in/up" page.

2) User signs in, and the router directs the user to a "welcome to the application" page

3) User navigates through the application to "pageOne" and then decides to sign out, and is again presented with the "Welcome but please sign-in/up" page being rendered. (However, the URL still reads http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/pageOne)

4) User signs-in again, where now the application should instead of rendering the "pageOne" page, which is the behavior of this.next(), be presented with the "welcome to the application" page.

I was able to get to this functionality with the code below:

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'layout', 
});

Router.route('/', {name: 'welcome'});
Router.route('/pageOne', {name: 'pageOne'});
Router.route('/pageTwo', {name: 'pageTwo'});

var requireLogin = function() {
if (! Meteor.user()) {
if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
Router.go('welcome');
} else {
this.render('welcomeButLogin');
}
} else {
this.next();
}
}

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {except: ['blah']});
```

This works, but I am getting a warning message of:

```
Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?
```

Thank you for taking the time, any feedback would be much appreciated.

Gene.

Comment: you need a this.next() after this.render('welcomeButLogin') I believe.

Comment: Thank you Ramsay. I made this change, however, now with the this.next() after "welcomeButLogin", even when the user signs out, they still have access to the "pageOne" page. Thank you for your comment though.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I changed:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {except: ['blah']});
```

to:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin);
```

per suggested code by solarc on the meteor forum (thanks solarc). I don't quite understand how this changes the routing specific behavior, since I interpreted that "{except" ['blah']}" would mean all routes since I did not have a "blah" route. I'll investigate further, but for now it works as expected, and I am not getting the warning message.

Thanks!